# Can I pass an argument into my decorator function when I call the inner/decorated function?

Tags: python, decorator

Hopefully that terminology is correct. I have this decorator function, which reads a text file:

```
def read_commands(inner, path=BATCH_PATH):
    with open(path) as f:
        commands = ['python ' + line.replace('\n', '') for line in f]

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for command in commands:
            inner(command, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

And here's one of the functions it decorates:

```
@read_commands
def execute_multi_commands(command, count):
    LOG.info(f'Executing command {count}: {command}')
    os.system(command)
    count += 1
```

I want to be able to change path from default when I call `execute_multi_commands`, like so in my `main`:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch', action='store', type=str, dest='batch')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    count = 1
    execute_multi_commands(count, path=args.batch)
```

However, obviously this does not work as `path` is not an argument in `execute_multi_commands`. Is it possible for me to pass `path` to the decorator function `read_commands`, when I call `execute_multi_commands`? - or, more likely, any functionally equivalent alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, at least the way your decorator is written. When you decorate a function, it's similar to doing:

```py
def execute_multi_commands(command, count):
    LOG.info(f'Executing command {count}: {command}')
    os.system(command)
    count += 1

execute_multi_commands = read_commands(execute_multi_commands)
```

So after this point, `read_commands` has already been executed, and the file has been read.

What you can do is change the decorator to read the file in the wrapper, something like:

```py
def read_commands(inner, path=BATCH_PATH):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        if "path" in kwargs:
            path_ = kwargs.pop("path")
        else:
            path_ = path

        with open(path_) as f:
            commands = ['python ' + line.replace('\n', '') for line in f]

        for command in commands:
            inner(command, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

...but this means reading the file every time you call the decorated function, which is slightly different than what you were doing before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not too familiar with using `kwargs` unfortunately, so I may be missing something - what is the `c` object in the line `path = c.pop("path")`?

Comment: Holt: The paths seen could be cached to avoid reading the associated files more than once.

Comment: Colin: The `path=BATCH_PATH` _is_ used when no `path` keyword argument is passed to `execute_multi_commands()`.